# email page hyperlink on sharepoint page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

Hi I am trying create a email link on sharepoint page i wrote forllowing script

```
function emailstory() 
    {
        mail_str = "mailto:?subject=" + document.title;
        mail_str += "&body= " + document.body + "\\n";
        mail_str += location.href;
        location.href = mail_str;
    }
<a href="javascript:emailstory()">E-mail a story</a>
```

In email body: i need sharepoint page description. How can i add that object to java script. Please let me know

Answer (score 1):

using Client Object Model:

```
var spweb;

function doStuff(){
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.spweb = clientContext.get_web();

    clientContext.load(this.spweb);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,  this.alertDescrp),Function.createDelegate(this, this.fail));
}

function alertDescrp(){
    alert(this.spweb.get_description());
}

function fail(){
    alert('failed');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go for Client Object Model?

[See if the answer in this page helps you or not](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/72ecf0ef-c340-40d4-9bac-025980e993a0/get-the-description-of-a-site-and-display-it-in-a-cewp?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)